# Split colon comma but ignore brackets in R?

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a data frame, and I want to split the strings in the `Mem` column by commas and colons. Here's my example:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=c("AM", "UA", "AS"),
                 Mem = c("WRR(World Happiness Report Index,WHRI)(Cs):1470,Country(%):60.2,UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s):1380,City(%):69.7,TSSB/Cs(%):93.88,Note:pass",
                         "WRR(World Happiness Report Index,WHRI)(Cs):2280,Country(%):96.2,UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s):2010,City(%):107.5,TSSB/Cs(%):88.16,Note:pass",
                         "WRR(World Happiness Report Index,WHRI)(Cs):3170,Country(%):101.6,UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s):2950,City(%):95.5,TSSB/Cs(%):93.06,Note:pass"))
```

I want to split the strings in the `Mem` column by colon and comma. The result should be:

```r
    ID  WRR(Happiness Report Index,HRI)(Cs)  Country(%)  UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s)  City(%)  TSSB/Cs(%)  Note
1:  AM  1470  60.2  1380   69.7  93.88  pass
2:  UA  2280  96.2  2010  107.5  88.16  pass
3:  AS  3170 101.6  2950   95.5  93.06  pass
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `":[^,]+,*"` can separate the variable names from its values. It means:

- A `:`;
- Folowed by any number of (`+`) characters, except commas (`[^,]`);
- Then, perhaps (`*`), a comma `,`;

We can then save these names on a variable with:

```
variables <- str_split_1(df$Mem[1], ":[^,]+,*") %>% head(-1)
```

Obs: the pattern ends up creating an empty string at the end, hence the `head(-1)`.

Then, to get the values, we want the rest of the string. We can do that by removing every element of `variables` from it. I don't know if there's already a function that does this, but here is a custom one:

```
str_remove_multiple <- function(x, patterns){
  for(i in patterns) x <- str_remove_all(x, fixed(i))
  x
}
```

After "cleaning" the Mem variable, we can split it by the remaining `","`, and save each value to a new column based on `variables`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Mem = str_remove_list(Mem, c(variables, ":"))) %>%
  separate(Mem, into = variables, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(across(-c(ID, Note), as.numeric))
```

**Result:**

```
  ID WRR(World Happiness Report Index,WHRI)(Cs) Country(%) UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s) City(%) TSSB/Cs(%) Note
1 AM                                       1470       60.2                                  1380    69.7      93.88 pass
2 UA                                       2280       96.2                                  2010   107.5      88.16 pass
3 AS                                       3170      101.6                                  2950    95.5      93.06 pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Can this help?:

```
dt = setDT(tstrsplit(df$Mem, "([^0-9.]+:)", keep=2:7, type.convert=TRUE))
setnames(dt, unlist(strsplit(df$Mem[1], "(:[^,]+,)|(:pass$)")))

   WRR(World Happiness Report Index,WHRI)(Cs) Country(%) UAM(The Star Spangled Banner,TSSB)(s) City(%) TSSB/Cs(%)   Note
                                        <int>      <num>                                 <int>   <num>      <num> <char>
1:                                       1470       60.2                                  1380    69.7      93.88   pass
2:                                       2280       96.2                                  2010   107.5      88.16   pass
3:                                       3170      101.6                                  2950    95.5      93.06   pass
```